# How can I use `form_for` resource-oriented style without `url:`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I tried

```
= form_for [@user, @subscription], html: {id: 'subscription_form'} do |f|
```

(ActionController::UnknownFormat) and

```
= form_for @subscription, html: {id: 'subscription_form'} do |f|
```

(undefined method `subscription_path') but it didn't work. This is working however:

```
= form_for @subscription, url: user_subscription_path(@user), html: {id: 'subscription_form'} do |f|
```

My routes:

```
  resources :users do
    resource :subscription, only: [:edit, :new, :create, :update, :destroy]
```

and

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\>rake routes | grep subscription
   new_user_subscription GET    /users/:user_id/subscription/new(.:format)  subscriptions#new
  edit_user_subscription GET    /users/:user_id/subscription/edit(.:format) subscriptions#edit
       user_subscription PATCH  /users/:user_id/subscription(.:format)      subscriptions#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/subscription(.:format)      subscriptions#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/subscription(.:format)      subscriptions#destroy
                         POST   /users/:user_id/subscription(.:format)      subscriptions#create
```

`user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :subscription
```

I don't see anything in the docs for this situation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: Your first approach is correct. The error `ActionController::UnknownFormat` is to with request format that is hitting the controllers action. Can you update the question with the related server log as well with the controller code?

Comment: The first approach generates links like `/users/1/subscription.1`. It's treating `.1` as a format. It probably calls `user_subscription_path(@user, @subscription)` and the second parameter is the `:format`, but uses the `id` of the model as the format.

Comment: Can you post the controller code?`subscription.1` is weird.

Comment: It is indeed weird. `irb(main):007:0> app.user_subscription_path(@user, @subscription)
=> "/users/1/subscription.1"`. But it's probably for a purpose `irb(main):009:0> app.user_subscription_path(@user, :json)
=> "/users/1/subscription.json"`.

Comment: Could you please post the controller code?